# How can i import arabic data into oracle database?

Tags: linux, oracle11g, arabic, sql-loader

I have an `excel` file with `arabic` data in `windows` , now I want to import this file into my `oracle` database which installed in `oracle linux 5.9`.
I exported my excel file as `csv` format but `linux` couldn't display arabic data
I used `sqlldr` and import csv file into database but unfortunately arabic data marked as question mark.

I dont hve any problem in insert and display arabic characters when I use `insert` statement, my characterset is `AR8MSWIN1256`.

Now how can I import arabic data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you specify the character set in the control file?

Comment: CHARACTERSET char_set_name as seen in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1006645 scroll down to the "characterset parameter section.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround that works for me

1. Save the excel file as "Unicode text (*.txt)
2. Open the text file, you'll find every column separated from neighboring columns by a "tab", copy that tab and "find+replace" it with a comma "," in the entire file.
3. If there's extra tabs at the end of the table it will result in a series of extra commas, delete those!
4. Save the file then manually change its extension from (.txt) to (.csv)

The file should now display the Arabic characters normally, and you can export it to any application as a CSV file